# What does "poor suppression of CSF signal in the basal cisterns" mean?

Tags: mri, csf-cerebrospinal-fluid

What does *"poor suppression of CSF signal in the basal cisterns"* mean in head MRI findings? I've tried googling for it, but couldn't find anything about it.